# Is there a way of splitting the existing file path directory in Ansible & using that later in the task?

Tags: split, ansible, strip

I am new to Ansible & trying to figure out this thing of splitting up directory path so that I can store the new path in new variable & use it later. I am dropping the draft of my playbook below.

```
---
- name: new directory path
  hosts: servers
  become: true
  become_user: root
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - name: directory path1
      file:
        path: /home/usr/Desktop/hello/hello1
      register: path1
    
    - name: splitting path
      file:
        path: path1.split('/')
      register: path2
```

What I want is to extract: /home/usr/Desktop/hello from /home/usr/Desktop/hello/hello1 and store it in a new variable path2 so that I can use path2 later.
Please suggest what shall I follow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [dirname](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8) filter to get a directory from a path. Below code snippet will set `/home/usr/Desktop/hello` to `dir`.

*Note, do not add a trailing `/` to the given path otherwise ansible will consider that the directory and will return the same path.*

```yaml
- set_fact:
    dir: "{{ '/home/usr/Desktop/hello/hello1' | dirname }}"
```

Comment: Oh, yes Thanks helps me a lot!! I am able to get the directory using dirname. I can use the variable itself instead of the path: ```` -set_fact: dir: "{{path1|dirname}}" ```` –